# How to select multiple attributes/classes in jQuery/js?

Tags: javascript, class

I have a js code to for tabbed content, where I select div of class .tab_nav, but I want to select another class .tab_content for the same code. How to do this?

```
{for(var d=document.getElementsByTagName("div"),c=0,e=d.length;
c<e;c++)a(d[c],"tab_nav")&&k.push(new b(d[c],c))};
```

Comment: Are you sure that's jQuery code?

Comment: Yes it inside a function, but how can I select another class as like 'tab_nav'?

Comment: Do you usually make you code so unreadable - ps where is the JQuery bit

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery with multiple selectors and assign methods or run code by separating them with commas ",".

IE.

```
$("#divName, .className, tagName").click(function(){ /* do your stuff*/});
```

Or

```
$("#divName, .className, tagName").each(...);
```